# How to create dividing lines in Navigation

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to build a navigation bar with dividing lines between each category. Why do the lines not extend to the left end of the navigation bar? I tried "hr" tags, creating lines with div-tags (width: 100% too) and reducing the margin but nothing seems to work.

Here is my code:

```css
#navbar{
    width: 10vw;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: red;
}

nav > ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    border-bottom: 3px solid;
    border-top: 3px solid;
}

nav > ul > li{
    border-bottom: 5px solid;
}
```

```html
    <nav id="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li>A</li><hr>
            <li>A</li><hr>
            <li>A</li><hr>
            <li>A</li><hr>
            <li>A</li><hr>
            <li>A</li><hr>
            <li>A</li><hr>
            <li>A</li><hr>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

This  is the Problem:

[image]

Comment: Remove the padding on the ul

Comment: Probably the 40px of padding on the parent `<ul>`; this is why most people apply some form of [tag:css-reset] to remove, or reset, browser default settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unordered list items (UL) have a default padding. You can set it to 0, then give your list item (LI) a padding on the left to push it over.

```css
#navbar{
    width: 10vw;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: red;
}

nav > ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    border-bottom: 3px solid;
    border-top: 3px solid;
    padding:0;
}

nav > ul > li{
    border-bottom: 5px solid;
    padding-left:20px;
}
```

```html
<nav id="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li>A</li><hr>
            <li>A</li><hr>
            <li>A</li><hr>
            <li>A</li><hr>
            <li>A</li><hr>
            <li>A</li><hr>
            <li>A</li><hr>
            <li>A</li><hr>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```